# Llama StorageContext.from_defaults takes too long

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, llama, llama-index

I am using llama to construct an index on some big data that I have, in order to build a chatbot off of it.  This is how im constructing the index

```
llm_predictor_chat = LLMPredictor(llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106"))
    embeddings = LangchainEmbedding(OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-ada-002"))
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor_chat, embed_model=embeddings)

    
    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()
    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents,service_context=service_context)
    index.storage_context.persist(directory_path + '/index.json')
```

Then when i message the chatbot, i get the index by doing this

```
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="{}/index.json".format(subreddit))
index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context)
```

But the problem is, this StorageContext.from_defaults takes over a minute to run so thus, chatbot responses are slow. Is there anyway to make it faster? or perhaps load it once and save it somewhere to re-use?

Thanks

I tried loading it in memory on digital ocean server, but after the first message is sent, it seems like the index memory is destroyed for some reason